# Why cannot convert from EntityLayer.SomeClass to DataLayer.SomeTable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I want to insert a row into a database and such an error occurs: "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'EntityLayer.PriceList' to 'DataLayer.tbl_PriceList'".

I'm writing an app that features adding some rows do database tables so I tried a method from learn.microsoft.com.

In PriceLists.cs

```
namespace EntityLayer
{
    public class PriceList
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string entry { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In UserService.cs

```
using EntityLayer;
using DataLayer;

namespace BusinessLayer
{  
  public void insertNewTicket()
  {
      using (AquaparkDBDataContext db = new AquaparkDBDataContext())
      {
          PriceList pr = new PriceList
          {
              entry = "pobrane",
              price = 0
          };

          db.tbl_PriceLists.InsertOnSubmit(pr);                
          db.SubmitChanges();
      }
   }
}
```

I'd expect the DB table "tbl_PriceLists" to update but I only get the error instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert a PriceList in place of a tbl_PriceLists. Your data context doesn't know what PriceList is. You have to map it. I am assuming you have an `entry` and `price` properties on tbl_PriceList.

```
using (AquaparkDBDataContext db = new AquaparkDBDataContext())
  {
      PriceList pr = new PriceList
      {
          entry = "pobrane",
          price = 0
      };

      db.tbl_PriceLists.InsertOnSubmit(new tbl_PriceLists{
             entry = pr.entry,
             price = pr.price
      });                
      db.SubmitChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Or you can use automapper too to map the tables and then insert. The posted one is easier to do when fields are less.

Comment: @Sumitraj sure, you can use the Automapper.